# Unable to connect to database using jsp in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am trying to connect with the mysql database in linux. I know I am making mistake in including the jar file. I don't know how to give reference to those jar files in linux the way we reference them in eclipse or Netbeans. I am running those jsp pages using tomat7.

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /first.jsp at line 9

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /first.jsp at line 9

6:  <%
7:
8:  out.println("Hello World!");
9:  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
10:     Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MeshliumDB","myuser","mypass");
11:     if(con!=null)
12:         out.println("Connection Established");

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
    org.apache.jsp.first_jsp._jspService(first_jsp.java:86)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:126)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    org.apache.jsp.first_jsp._jspService(first_jsp.java:73)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)

Comment: Add mysql jar file in lib.

Comment: I don't know how to add that jar file in the lib... can you please tell me @praveen_programmer

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar file in the WEB-INF/lib of your directory present inside webapps of tomcat.

OR

Download mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar
And add using following procedure.

1. Go to project properties by right clicking on project.
2. Then click on Libraries tab, You will see Compile, Run, Compile Tests, Run Tests tabs.
3. Click on Compile tab
4. Click on Add JAR/Folder button at right
5. Then browse and select the jar files or folder which you want to include. Included jar files or libraries will show on  the following box of Compile tab.
6. Click on OK button.
7. Finished.

See link .

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqhQY7U9Rlc&feature=youtu.be

https://jsumon.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/adding-external-jar-or-library-to-netbeans-java-project/

Comment: I know that...
I am not using any kind eclipse or netbeans. I am just using sumlime text editor. I have written the code for connection now the problem which I facing is that, it is not able to load the driver because jar file is not added.

Comment: Yo can add jar in lib directory.Where all other library placed.

Comment: yeah I did that also... but I think we need to specify classpath so that those driver get loaded. I don't know how to do that